# Count occurences in a row of a char in string

Tags: java, string, char

Is there any way to count occurences of a char in string in a row in Java?
For example, given string: `ABBB99999SHJ99JI`, will output that `9` char was find in a string once: 5 times in a row and twice: 2 times in a row.
I tried to find the solution, but without result.

It is possible to find it with regex, but for each amount of numbers i need to create a separate one.

Comment: You can iterate over the characters of a `String` and count their occurrences.

Comment: @deHaar I don't want to find the occurences. I want to count how many occurences there is in a row

Comment: I think the simplest way is to just use a `for` loop and count the occurences

Comment: @Nosrep, well I can count occurences. I need to count that in a row. I mean, you have string ABBBSB, and you search for B. Then output will be 'once, 3times in a row and once, 1time in a row'

Comment: Even for that the loop will work, you will probably need two nested loops.

Comment: @Goion what should I do in a second loop? I try to find the solution for the past 2 days

Comment: What is your input? A large `String` containing *rows*? That would possibly mean the input contains line separators that could be used to distinguish rows. How does your entire input look? If it is too large to show, describe it please.

Comment: you would compare it to the character from outer loop. As long as they are same, keep incrementing the occurrence counter. Once they differ, set the outer loop index to the current char.

Comment: @deHaar: my input is a binary string, for example: 000001011110111011100001010101. I need to count how many ones are in a row and how many zeros. In row,  I mean one after other

Comment: OK and how can one know where a row begins or ends?

Comment: User doesn't input that. I generate that and store in a String. Each value is set under one index of a given string.

Comment: @Goion that's a great idea!

Comment: @Alice you can simplify and implement in a single loop using 2 variable(pointer) method like `startIndex` and `endIndex` . Update them when you find a match/mismatch

Comment: @Sanket9394 Thanks! I try to implement the ideas

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using regexp as you mentioned:

- create a regexp to find groups containing at least one character, e.g. `([9]+)`
- find the groups in a loop and collect their lengths.

```java
public static List<Integer> countGroupLengths(String src, char c) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(c + "+"); // e.g. `9+` works too
    Matcher m = p.matcher(src);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        String group = m.group(1);
        result.add(group.length());
    }
    return result;
}
```

test:

```java
System.out.println(countGroupLengths("ABBB99999SHJ99JI", '9'));
```

output:

```
[5, 2]
```

**Update**
It may be worth to build a map for each character to the list of lengths
integrating all the changes offered by @Andreas in the comments:

```java
public static Map<Character, List<Integer>> buildMapOfGroups(String src) {

    return src.chars()     // IntStream
              .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
              .map(c -> Map.entry(
                      c, // key
                      Pattern.compile(c + "+").matcher(src)
                             .results()
                             .map(r -> r.group().length())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList())
              ))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                  Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, 
                  (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

For the given source: `System.out.println(buildMapOfGroups("ABBB99999SHJ99JI"));`
prints:

```
{A=[1], B=[3], 9=[5, 2], S=[1], H=[1], J=[1, 1], I=[1]}
```

*Note: using LinkedHashMap to keep the order of insertion*

Comment: Thank you a lot! That's what I searched for.

Comment: `([9]+)` is excessive. Use `9+`, then replace `group(1)` with `group()` or `group(0)`, will do it.

Comment: *FYI:* In Java 9+, the method can be written as `return Pattern.compile(c + "+").matcher(src).results().map(r -> r.group().length()).collect(Collectors.toList());`